# Route subnet over network windows

Tags: windows, networking, routing

I'm trying to get access to a bunch of testing equipment that is connected to a different PC which cannot be connected to the company-wide internal network.

PC-A ist the PC I'm working at, PC-B is a different PC in the same company network, which has a second network card that is connected to a bunch of test devices. I want to share PC-B's second network card so I can directly access the devices connected to PC-B from PC-A. Ideally the connection would only be possible with PC-B's login credentials.

Setup overview:

```
| PC-A       |       | PC-B          |             | Prototype-   |
| 10.11.0.23 |-------| 10.11.0.25    |  testnet    | devices      |
|            |       | 192.168.10.20 |-------------| 192.168.10.* |
```

The IP-Addresses in the 10.11.0.* network are dynamic, so static routes are not that easy, the PCs do have fixed hostnames though. They both run windows 7. PC-B is being used by a colleague and we would both need access to the network at the same time.

On a *nix system I would accomplish this using ssh, but I don't know how / if this is possible in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Known hostname" and "PC-B's credentials" can be combined to "**set up a VPN service** on PC-B" – once connected, the routes will be set up automatically in one direction, and shouldn't be necessary at all in the reverse direction.

IIRC, even the client editions of Windows have a few VPN servers built-in – e.g. although PPTP is utter junk for remote access, it still works well as a local dynamic-tunnelling protocol, and automatically uses Windows accounts.

Alternatively, there's OpenVPN.

Comment: Right, OpenVPN would probably be the most painless option here...